# Reading text after a specific character with PHP

Tags: php, text, explode

I am trying to read some text after a specific character and then retrieve the data. I am able to do this, but I want to be able to separate out the data with '#' so that it's separated individually. I can sort of manage this but the problem is that on some parts there is a space instead of a hashtag.

I've tried using `$info = explode(' = ', rtrim($file, '#'));` but that doesn't work. I have also tried some other solutions that didn't work either.

This is my code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('LauncherInfo.txt');
$info = explode(' = ', $file);

echo $info[0].'#'.$info[1].'#'.$info[2].'#'.$info[3].'#'.$info[4];
```

This is the output I get with that code.

```
IP#127.0.0.1 EXE#Client.exe PORT#8080 TITLE#Launcher
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
IP#127.0.0.1#EXE#Client.exe#PORT#8080#TITLE#Launcher
```

Also this is my txt file:

```
IP = 127.0.0.1
EXE = Client.exe
PORT = 8080
TITLE = Launcher
```

Thanks for reading, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $file=file('LauncherInfo.txt');

foreach ($file as $line) {

$line=str_replace(' = ','#',$line);
$line=preg_replace('%\r\n%','#',$line);

echo $line; 

}
```

Comment: Oh I see what you did there. That's quite clever and exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

user trim() function to remove the spaces from right and left,

```
 echo trim($info[0]).'#'.trim($info[1]).'#'.trim($info[2]).'#'.trim($info[3]).'#'.trim($info[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
$str = 'IP#127.0.0.1 EXE#Client.exe PORT#8080 TITLE#Launcher';

echo str_replace(' ', '#', $str);
```

This will output

```
IP#127.0.0.1#EXE#Client.exe#PORT#8080#TITLE#Launcher
```

[Live sample](http://ideone.com/gIxkLL)

Comment: Yes that's possible, but I want to be able to read it from a text file. If I wanted to do it normally I think I could just echo what the output would be.

Comment: @farbodD please check my live sample, it is actually the same thing as charging from a file

Comment: Oh I see you changed it. But wouldn't that require me to have a space after whatever I have written in my original text file.

Comment: @FarbodD the space i changed will be always generated because of the new line in the file